# Filter custom post types in archive

Tags: filters, query

I want to filter my custom posts (pump) with a custom filter form on it's archive page (archive-pump.php).

So, I wrote the form markup:

```
<form method="GET">
    <label>Series</label>
    <?php
        if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'series', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) :
            echo '<select name="series">';
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
            endforeach;
            echo '</select>';
        endif;
    ?>
    <button type="submit">Apply filter</button>
</form>
```

And I have this to output my custom posts:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title( '', '', true ); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

When I open my page (localhost/project/pumps) it looks fine.
But when I submit my form I'm getting an 404 page.

I maybe need an seperate query to fetch all the $_GET data. But I'm not getting to the step because of the 404 error.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: When you submit the form, what's the URL? Have you considered linking to the terms archive instead?

Comment: The URL is: http://localhost/project/pumps/?series=7
It looks okay, but I'm getting the 404
And I didn't understand your second question

Comment: and you're absolutely sure that it takes a term ID? I tried reproducing this with tags and could not get it to work, but `?tag=react` worked perfectly for me.

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I checked the custom taxonomx ID in the backend

Comment: I didn't mean are you sure the term ID is right, but I meant are you sure you need to use a term ID? Not a term slug? `?tag=react` worked for me, but using the `react` terms ID did not. I'm assuming though that there is no `query_posts` call on this page?

Comment: Yes, this worked perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using term IDs in your URL, but that is incorrect.

Use the term slug instead.

For example, lets say we have a `mytax` term named `helloworld` with the term ID 1:

- `example.com/cpt/?mytax=1` 404
- `example.com/cpt/?mytax=helloworld` a cpt archive filtered by the `helloworld` term

Comment: Oh, wow! Thank you! 

Comment: awesome, if this answers your question, consider marking it as the correct answer, it's the big tick under the voting arrows